# Integrating Prolog with C#

Tags: c#, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I am new to Prolog and C#. When I try to integrate Prolog with C# I found some errors,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SbsSW.SwiPlCs;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SWI_HOME_DIR", @"the_PATH_to_boot32.prc");  // or boot64.prc
            if (!PlEngine.IsInitialized)
            {
                String[] param = { "-q" };  // suppressing informational and banner messages
                PlEngine.Initialize(param);
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(martin, inka))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, gloria))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, melanie))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(uwe, ayala))");
                using (var q = new PlQuery("father(P, C), atomic_list_concat([P,' is_father_of ',C], L)"))
                {
                    foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
                        Console.WriteLine(v["L"].ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine("all children from uwe:");
                    q.Variables["P"].Unify("uwe");
                    foreach (PlQueryVariables v in q.SolutionVariables)
                        Console.WriteLine(v["C"].ToString());
                }
                PlEngine.PlCleanup();
                Console.WriteLine("finished!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not running, Before run this I was add reference SwiPlCs.dll. But it shows error "FileNotFoundException was unhandled, The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)".

So can anyone help me to fix this error?

I got this coding [here](http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx)

Comment: Do you mean you're new to *both* Prolog *and* C#? If so, I would really try to get comfortable with *at least* one of them, ideally both of them, before you integrate them together. The exception should show which file couldn't be found, by the way - look for all the details in an error message.

Comment: There is a similar question with similar error.. pls try that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556887/interface-prolog-with-c-sharp

Comment: Btw there is also a nuget package http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555200/how-to-interfacing-swi-prolog-to-the-visual-studio-2012?rq=1

Comment: @JonSkeet I have basic knowledge in Prolog and I have done some projects using C#. But integration is difficult to me. Anyway Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you've provided has full explanation of this error:

> If `libswipl.dll` or one of its dependencies could not found you will recive an error like 
>   `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>
> An other common error is:
>
> ```
> SWI-Prolog: [FATAL ERROR:
>   Could not find system resources]`  
>   Failed to release stacks
> ```
>
> To fix this add the `SWI_HOME_DIR` environment variable as described in [SWI-Prolog FAQ FindResources](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/FindResources.html) with a statment like this befor calling `PlEngine.Initialize`.
>
> ```
> Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SWI_HOME_DIR", @"the_PATH_to_boot32.prc");
> ```

This code is commented by default, Uncomment it and provide the correct path to the `the_PATH_to_boot32.prc`. As described in FAQ:

> **Solution**
>
> On Windows, it suffices to leave `libswipl.dll` in the installation tree (**i.e., do not copy it elsewhere**) and add the bin directory of the installation tree to `%PATH%`.
>
> A cross-platform and robust solution is to use `putenv()` to put an appropriate path into the environment before calling `PL_initialise()`.
>
> ```
> ...;
> putenv("SWI_HOME_DIR=C:\\Program Files\\swipl");
> if ( PL_initialise(argc, argv) )
>   PL_halt(1);
> ...
> ```
>
> In the final version of your application you link the saved-state to the executable (using `swipl-ld` or `cat` (Unix)) and comment the `putenv()` call.

Comment: @KALYANI YOu can set this answer as accepted if you found it useful :)

Comment: But i couldn't fix the error.
I add the path like this,

 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SWI_HOME_DIR", @"C:\Program Files\swipl\bin");
But nothing happend

Comment: @KALYANI Try to remove `bin` from the path